# Problem generating GET url

Tags: java, url

I am working on Java. I am calling a GET url on my own machine using Java. Here is the url string with the arguments.

```
listen.executeUrl("http://localhost/post_message.php?query_string="+str);
```

I am taking str as user input.

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 System.out.print("Enter query: ");
 str = br.readLine();
```

How do I encode str into GET argument. For eg.

```
str -> test query

url -> http://localhost/post_message.php?query_string=test%20query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
```

Note that URLEncoder replaces spaces with `+`, not `%20`. Here is a [detailed discussion](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2008/02/uri-escaping-and-javaneturlencoder) of the differences.

Comment: Isn't using '+' in a query string accepted practice, even if not strictly correct, it works in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `encode()` method of the `java.net.URLEncoder` class.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to encode your query string, e.g.

```
str = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
```

You set the second argument to the encoding that your server is configured for.

See [URLEncoder.encode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))